# What's TagSuggestion and TagPrediction in the mod post history?

Tags: support, moderator-tools

When looking at the mod post history of a question here on meta I saw those entries which I've never seen before:

```
4 hours ago         TagSuggestion                 
4 hours ago         TagPrediction           hyperlinks post-ban chat
```

Is this a new feature? What exactly does it do?

Comment: Meta seems to suggest tags at the bottom when you're asking a new question. I saw it once at least...maybe that's what this is? Not sure why mods would care though

Comment: I think it's just part of the history of a post that devs would be interested in _mostly_, but perhaps mods if there was some bug or issue with suggested tags (e.g. it suggested something horrible and the user went with it). Doesn't hurt to show us.